# Is there a way to get the class name of a constructor from a passed in object in php?

Tags: php, dependency-injection

Imagine I have a class structure as follows:

```
class Logger {
    public function __construct(string $channel) {    
        // Logger initialization stuff
    }
}

class UsingLogger {
    private Logger $logger;
    
    public function __construct(Logger $logger) { 
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }
}


$logger = new Logger("UsingLogger");
$usingLogger = new UsingLogger($logger);
```

This works just fine. The channel is the name of the class, in this case. However, I want to use PHP DI (https://php-di.org/doc/php-definitions.html#autowired-objects) to resolve this case. The issue is that it can't resolve cases like this because it doesn't know the class name that the logger is passed into.

Example PhpDI definition

```
    return [
        "SomeLoggerInterface" => autowire(Logger::class)->constructorParameter("channel", // somehow get the name of the class here. In this case, it would be "UsingLogger")
    ]
```

I hope this makes sense. If there's any more context needed, let me know

I've outlined my steps above

Comment: this look like circular reference design problem, not quite but close, because its just a string with class name and not instance, but that brake the same rule. in your case it could work, but you must know beforehand which class it will be, doesn't matter how you store and use that information but that is requirement of your design. would be much easier if you could change your design, lets say the `$channel` would be defaulted with added setter method and `UsingLogger` calling that setter on `Logger` object which is autowired, this way the instantiation of `UsingLogger` dictates the channel.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you've installed DI package.

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

final class Logger
{
    public function __construct(private readonly string $channel) {}
}

final class UsingLogger {
    public function __construct(private readonly Logger $logger) {}
}

$container = new DI\Container([
    'channel' => 'UsingLogger',
    'Logger' => DI\create()->constructor(DI\get('channel')),
    'UsingLogger' => DI\create()->constructor(DI\get('Logger')),
]);

final class TestClass
{
    public function __construct(UsingLogger $usingLogger) {
        var_dump($usingLogger);
    }
}

new TestClass($container->get('UsingLogger'));
```

Running this script would produce following output:

```
php index.php
path/to/script.php:25:
class UsingLogger#20 (1) {
  private readonly Logger $logger =>
  class Logger#25 (1) {
    private readonly string $channel =>
    string(11) "UsingLogger"
  }
}
```

Perhaps you also should to use interfaces as well. Hope this helps.